# While using jenkins API, getting a failure on attribute 'Jenkins'

Tags: python, macos, jenkins-api

I am executing my script on Mac (macOS 10.14.1) using Python (2.7.10).
This is what i have in my script:

```
server_jenkins = jenkins.Jenkins(JENKINS_URL, username=JENKINS_USER, password=JENKINS_PASS)
```

And this is the error i am getting:

```
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Jenkins'
```

Comment: Looks like you have a script named `jenkins.py` rename that and it should work.

Comment: @Rakesh this is not true, why do you think so?

Answer (score 1):

That's because you using the wrong package,
to solve this problem, please use the flowing commands

```
sudo pip uninstall jenkins 
sudo pip install python-jenkins
```

Answer (score 0):

The error means that `jenkins` module has no class (read attribute) named `Jenkins`. Since this is not true for the actual `jenkins` module, it is likely that you have a file called `jenkins.py` which is being read and processed by the code.

Comment: Where am i supposed to have a file named "jenkins.py"? there is not such file in the same folder where i have my python script.

Comment: I am trying to execute the same script from 2 different mac machines. From one it works fine, from the second i am getting the error message i attached.

Comment: You should look for jenkins.py in the machine where this is failing. Do a `find . -name "jenkins.py"` in the root of your project.